# Php echo and print different behavior in for loop?

Tags: php, for-loop, echo

Example 1

`for($var=1;$var<=5;print $var,$var++);`  //valid

Example 2

`for($var=1;$var<=5;echo $var,$var++);`  //invalid

the behavior of above two statements is not that straight, could any body explain why they are showing different results ?

Answer (score 5):

`echo` is a language construct, not a function. It has no return value. `print()` is a function, and DOES have a return value.

Ref: http://php.net/echo http://php.net/print

Comment: `print()` is also a language construct, but I assume that because `echo`'s syntax allows `echo 1, 2, 3` to output `123` which conflicts with the syntax for a loop declaration, so it's disallowed.

Comment: but it behaves as a function, because it has a return value. But yeah, probably that's it. the loop runs because $var++ will still increment, but echo will snag the `,` for itself.

Comment: But it's not a runtime error, it's a parse error. ;)

Answer (score 0):

While both `print` and `echo` are language constructs, the syntax defined for `echo` conflicts with what you are doing. Specifically:

```
echo 1, 2, 3, 4;
//output: 1234
```

This conflicts with the syntax for a loop definition, which is why I believe you're not permitted to use `echo` there.